# iText DocumentException

Tags: java, exception, itext, document

When does a `DocumentException` (iText) occur? I am trying to document my code and I want to add some explanation after the `@throws DocumentException` tag. I didn't find anything in the API.

Comment: _Signals that an error has occurred in a Document._ http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException.html

Comment: That's obvious enough, I want to know what kind of error can occur?

Comment: Could be one of these: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/BadElementException.html or http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfException.html

Answer (score 0):

When the document is not open (has been closed, or not yet opened).

Digging through the decompiled source, i find these lines:

```
if (this.close) {
    throw new DocumentException("the document has been closed you cant add any elements");
} else if (!this.open) {
    throw new DocumentException("the document is not open yet you can only add meta information");
}
```